# Writing a string repeater in C produces unwanted chars

Tags: c, string, repeat, chars

I'm trying to get a custom string repeater to work in C. It works for some input, and in other cases, it appends unwanted characters. It seems to me `malloc` in some cases allocates too much memory, but I don't quite grasp why.

**Examples:**

```
repeater("hi", 2) -> hihi

repeater("yeah", 4) -> yeahyeahyeahyeah?f{??
```

**The code:**

```
int length(char* str)
{
    int i;
    if(str == NULL)
        return 0;
    for(i = 0; *(str+i) != '\0'; ++i);
    return i;
}

char* repeater(char* str, int times)
{
    char* out;
    int i,len,sz;
    len = length(str);
    sz = len * times;
    out = (char*)malloc(sz * sizeof(char));
    for(i = 0; i < sz; i++)
        *(out+i) = *(str + (i % len));   
    return out;
}
```

Comment: You must null-terminate the result string.

Comment: Are you sure you are allocating sufficient space? What about the terminating character (i.e. `\0`) of the resulting string?

Comment: Why not use [`strlen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen) ? Why not use the more readable `str[i]` instead of `*(str+i)` ?

Comment: Appending the null character seems to terminate the resulting string correctly and therefore solves my issue. Thank you! @Sander: Purely to get acquainted with C and how it deals with pointers and whatnot :-)

Answer (score -1):

You don't need the length function, [**strlen**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strlen.htm) already do that for you AND it dont include the terminating null character.

so **len = length(str);** become **len = strlen(str);**

You need the string.h lib to work with it.

Look at this online version to see the change : https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/AiA

Comment: Thanks for your input, Maximilien. As stated above it was intended as an exercise to get acquainted with the C language. I'm aware that C has quite some libraries with similar functionalities, but that wasn't maybe too clear from the context.